# Delay in return value - nodejs & mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to nodejs and I'm doing a full stack developer challenge from devchallenges.io (Shoppingify). Below, I'm trying to increase the quantity value based on whether the user clicks to increase or decrease the item quantity. However, there's a slight delay between the return value from the request and the actual value in the database. It seems that the value updates immediately which is great however, the return value in the request is the previous value rather than being the current quantity value in the database.

mongoDB Database

[image]

[image]

```
// @route    PUT api/list/item/quantity/:id
// @desc     update item quantity
// @access   Private
router.put('/item/quantity/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { action } = req.body;
  try {
    let list = await List.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

    // find current quantity
    const item = list.items.find((item) => {
      return item._id.toString() === req.params.id;
    });

    // increase quantity
    if (action === 'increase') {
      list = await List.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'items._id': req.params.id },
        { $set: { 'items.$.quantity': item.quantity + 1 } },
        { new: true }
      );
    } else {
      // decrease quantity
      list = await List.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'items._id': req.params.id },
        { $set: { 'items.$.quantity': item.quantity - 1 } },
        { new: true }
      );
    }

    res.json(item.quantity);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `item` in here:

```
const item = list.items.find((item) => {
      return item._id.toString() === req.params.id;
    });
```

At this point `list` is the "old" version of the object, you want to be doing the same after the update when the `list` object is updated and only then to return it.

```
// this is the original "list" item
let item = list.items.find((item) => {
   return item._id.toString() === req.params.id;
});

...
update list
...

// now "list" is updated
item = list.items.find((item) => {
   return item._id.toString() === req.params.id;
});
```

I will just add two additional tips to improve performance, they are mutually exclusive so you'll have to choose one of the two.

1. in the update query add the `list._id` to it, If I were to guess the collection does not have an index on the `items` field ( and if it does it's a bad idea usually ). this means when you updated just using the `item._id` field it takes longer for mongo to find the object. it's quick change to both updates:

```
list = await List.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: list._id, 'items._id': req.params.id },
    { $set: { 'items.$.quantity': item.quantity - 1 } },
    { new: true }
);
```

2. (my preferred option) do it in a single call, using the update [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters) option, like so:

```
const list = await List.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        user: req.user.id,
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            'items.$[elem].quantity': action === 'increase' ? 1 : -1,
        },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'elem._id': new ObjectId(req.params.id),
            },
        ],
        new: true,
    });

const item = list.items.find((item) => {
    return item._id.toString() === req.params.id;
});
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iKZkuHTHNdn)

In my opinion now your route looks much better, you're also cutting down from 2 db calls to 1.

Comment: You're a star, thank you :)